# Need a loop to enter formulas/data in excel table columns

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, listobject

I am in need of a nested loop to add formulas to 4 particular columns in my table ("Table1"). I would like my For loop to mimic the previous For loop regarding the naming of these same 4 additional columns ("colNames").

The bottom portion of this code works just fine, but I would like to know how to work it into a loop.

```
Sub attStatPivInsertTableColumns_2()
Dim lst As ListObject
Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim colNames As Variant, formNames As Variant '<~~ NOTE: As Varient, this is your go to when working with arrays
Dim oLC As ListColumn, oLData As Variant
Dim i As Integer, d As Integer

Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set lst = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

colNames = Array("AHT", "Target AHT", "Transfers", "Target Transfers")

    For i = 0 To UBound(colNames) 
        Set oLC = lst.ListColumns.Add
        oLC.Name = colNames(i)
    Next i
          ***Below is the code that needs to be looped***                                
'lst.ListColumns("Target AHT").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=350"
'lst.ListColumns("Target Transfers").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=0.15"
'lst.ListColumns("AHT").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=([@[Inbound Talk Time (Seconds)]]+[@[Inbound Hold Time (Seconds)]]+[@[Inbound Wrap Time (Seconds)]])/[@[Calls Handled]]"
'lst.ListColumns("Transfers").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=[@[Call Transfers and/or Conferences]]/[@[Calls Handled]]"

End Sub
```

Here is what I am going for so far, but I am running into errors, for what are probably obvious reasons:

```
formNames = Array("=([@[Inbound Talk Time (Seconds)]]+[@[Inbound Hold Time (Seconds)]]+[@[Inbound Wrap Time (Seconds)]])/[@[Calls Handled]]", "=350", "=[@[Call Transfers and/or Conferences]]/[@[Calls Handled]]", "=0.15")
For d = 0 To UBound(formNames)
    For i = 0 To UBound(colNames)
        Set oLData = lst.ListColumns(i).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = "d"
    Next i
Next d
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Construct one more variant array containing the formulas/values you want to populate the new table columns with.

```
Sub insertTableColumn()
    Dim lst As ListObject
    Dim currentSht As Worksheet
    Dim h As Long, hdrs As Variant, r1c1s As Variant

    hdrs = Array("AHT", "Target AHT", "Transfers", "Target Transfers")
    r1c1s = Array("=([@[Inbound Talk Time (Seconds)]]+[@[Inbound Hold Time (Seconds)]]+[@[Inbound Wrap Time (Seconds)]])/[@[Calls Handled]]", _
                    350, _
                    "=[@[Call Transfers and/or Conferences]]/[@[Calls Handled]]", _
                    0.15)

    Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set lst = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")

    With lst 'ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")
        For h = LBound(hdrs) To UBound(hdrs)
            .ListColumns.Add
            .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).Name = hdrs(h)
            .ListColumns(.ListColumns.Count).DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = r1c1s(h)
        Next h
    End With

End Sub
```

I've also used pairs in a single array with `h = LBound(hdrs) To UBound(hdrs) Step 2` and `hdrs(h+1)` for the formulas/values.

Comment: So, correct me if I am wrong. I still have not tried this yet...does this negate the need for my first i loop, coded in my question? From what I am reading, it seems like it would with the '.ListColumns.Add' included the WITH statement.

Comment: In your original (as above) there would be another line directly after `oLC.Name = colNames(i)` with something like `oLC.DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = r1c1s(i)`.

Comment: Okay I'm with you, thanks. You're way is much more efficient. I never saw the LBound and UBound function before today. Worked great too.